# Replace a part of the string after being found in the text of an array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the `fText` string value `int b=3, a, c=10;` be changed into:

```
int _sc_b=3, _sc_a, _sc_c=10;
```

by using the text inside the array elements.

**My code:**

```
var fText = "int b=3, a, c=10;";

sc_var_int_temp[0] = "a";
sc_var_int_temp[1] = "b";
sc_var_int_temp[2] = "c";


for( var vi=0; vi<sc_var_int_temp.length; vi++ ){
    //how would i do the replacing?
}//for
```

**GOAL**: `fText` value will be  `int _sc_b=3, _sc_a, _sc_c=10;`

**UPDATE**: tried `fText.replace(sc_var_int_temp[vi], "_sc_"+sc_var_int_temp[vi] );` but hangs the system ^^

as much as possible, i intend to do the replacing **using the loop**

**UPDATE**

I realized that the answer i accepted will not work properly when fText is:

```
var fText = "int b=3,a ,c=10;";
//not really seperated by a single whitespace
```

Comment: I don't know what you're actually doing with this code, but this is a horrible way to store and assign values

Comment: what if one of vars is `i` or `n` or `t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It possibly won't catch every edge case, but works with your example input/output:

```
for( var vi=0; vi<sc_var_int_temp.length; vi++ ){
    fText = fText.split(' '+ sc_var_int_temp[vi] ).join( " _sc_" + sc_var_int_temp[vi] );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6YgHj/

Or without the loop

```
fText = fText.split(' ').join(' _sc_');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6YgHj/1/

So what you really want is to add a prefix to what seems like variable names in a string that declares the variables. You need a way to extract the variable names. I can't think of every possible way to declare variables in your source language. Is `"int a=1, float b,c"` valid? How about `"int a=10, b=2*a;"`?

Comment: @extraRice it's one of the edge cases I had in mind in the first sentence ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp:

```
var fText = "int b=3, a, c=10;";
fText = fText.replace(/(a|b|c)/g, "_sc_$1")
```

`/(a|b|c)/g` matches either a, b or c and assigns them as a separate match, because of the parens `()`. Then `"_sc_$1"` is the replacement whereby `$1` pulls back the letter that was actually matched.

See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc2NF/

Comment: Note, this will only change the one line, and not all subsequent references to the variable